# Can an expression return type be generic?

Tags: generics, expression

i'm using expressions. Is it possible to have a genric return type, so i want to return whatever the type of the property is thats passed into my expression.

```
  public PropertyMapping(Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> expression)
    {
        this.expression = expression;

        if (this.expression != null)
        {
            this.expressionMemberName =((MemberExpression)this.expression.Body).Member.Name;
        }
     }
```

I don't want to create StringPropertyMapping, IntPropertyMapping, DoublePropertyMapping etc....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a type parameter for the property type to your `PropertyMapping` class. If it's nested within a class which defines the `TEntity` type parameter, it will become `PropertyMapping<TProperty>`:

```
public class SomeClass<TEntity>
{
   public class PropertyMapping<TProperty>
   {
      public PropertyMapping(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression)
      {
         ...
```

If it's a top-level class, it will become `PropertyMapping<TEntity, TProperty>`:

```
public class PropertyMapping<TEntity, TProperty>
{
   public PropertyMapping(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression)
   {
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks! How does it know what T is? this is where i set up the expression: this.PropertyMapping(c => c.MyProperty);

Comment: That's type inference - the compiler knows the type of `c`, so it's able to work out the type of `c.MyProperty`, and infer that `TProperty` must be that type.